# Consulta que muestre nombres y conteo de votos en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy empezando a trabajar con MySQL en una encuesta y necesito imprimir los distintos nombres que tengo en mi tabla *CANDIDATO* y hacer un conteo de los votos que tiene cada uno en la tabla *VOTOS*, las tablas están referenciadas por el *ID_CANDIDATO.*

Estoy realizando un INNER JOIN pero no logro imprimir ambos a la vez.
Si hago el conteo no me muestra todos los nombres y si muestro los nombres no sé como mostrar cuantos votos tiene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta debería ser algo así como

```
SELECT C.nombre, COUNT(V.voto) AS votos 
FROM CANDIDATO C INNER JOIN VOTOS V ON C.id=V.id_candidato
GROUP BY C.id
```

Es importante agregar el `GROUP BY`, para diferenciar los diferentes candidatos

Comment: Mil gracias. Es justo lo que necesito. :)